Probability of Drawing a Fair Coin Given Two Consecutive Heads

In a box, there are 4 coins: two fair ones, one that lands heads 75%
of the time, and one with two heads. A coin is randomly drawn from the
box and flipped twice, resulting in two heads. What is the probability
that a fair coin was drawn from the box?

Let $A$ be the event of drawing the two-headed coin and $B$ its complement. We have $P(A)=\frac{1}{4}$, while $P(B)=\frac{3}{4}$. Let's calculate the probability of getting 2 heads in $B$:
To get heads-heads, we have the probability: $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$. Let $C_1$ be the event heads-heads, then: $P(C_B)$ will be the probability of getting heads twice in a coin that is not two-headed, i.e., $$P(C_B)=P(C_1|B)=\frac{P(C_1 \cap B)}{P(B)}$$
Thus, $$P(C_B)=\frac{\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot 0.75 + \frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2}{\frac{3}{4}}= \frac{7}{6}$$
How do I get the answer from this?

What's the probability of observing $HH$?  That's your denominator.  Your numerator is the portion of that attributable to having drawn a fair coin.

Your notation is hard to follow, I didn't really try.  I suggest, just condition on the drawn coin.  Simpler.

"In a box, there are 4 coins: two fair ones, one that lands heads 75% of the time, and one with two heads."

Let $A={$ 2 heads from 2 flips$}$. We know for $B_1={$fair coin$}$, $B_2={$unfair coin$}$ and $B_2={$only heads coin$}$, $P(B_1)=0.5$, $P(B_2)=P(B_3)=0.25$. Then $P(A|B_1)=\frac{1}{4}$, $P(A|B_2)=\frac{9}{16}$ and $P(A|B_3)=1$. We want to know $P(B_1|A)=\frac{P(A|B_1)P(A)}{P(A|B_1)P(B_1)+P(A|B_2)P(B_2)+P(A|B_3)P(B_3)}$, using Bayes' theorem.

The event of interest is that you drew a fair coin, given that two heads were observed.  Consequently it makes no sense to define events for drawing the two-headed coin versus not drawing the two-headed coin, because the latter event includes the biased coin.
What you want to do is define the event $A$ to mean that the coin drawn was fair.  Then you want to define two more events to represent the other two coins; for instance, $B$ is the event that the coin drawn was biased ($75\%$ heads), and $C$ is the event that the coin drawn was two-headed.  So what is the unconditional probability of drawing two heads?  The law of total probability states
$$\Pr[HH] = \Pr[HH \mid A]\Pr[A] + \Pr[HH \mid B]\Pr[B] + \Pr[HH \mid C]\Pr[C].$$
You know already that $$\Pr[A] = 2/4, \quad \Pr[B] = 1/4, \quad \Pr[C] = 1/4,$$ because each of the four coins is drawn with equal probability, and there are two fair coins.  And you know
$$\Pr[HH \mid A] = (1/2)(1/2) = 1/4, \quad \Pr[HH \mid B] = (3/4)(3/4) = 9/16, \quad \Pr[HH \mid C] = 1.$$
Now you can compute $\Pr[HH]$.  Finally, Bayes' rule gives us
$$\Pr[A \mid HH] = \frac{\Pr[HH \mid A]\Pr[A]}{\Pr[HH]}.$$
The numerator contains probabilities already described above; the computation is left as an exercise.
